# assign number every time an event occurs in r

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
t <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1)
dt <- data.table(t)

     t
 1: NA
 2: NA
 3: NA
 4:  1
 5: NA
 6: NA
 7: NA
 8: NA
 9:  1
10: NA
11:  1
```

Is it possible to create new column z and assign a number in ascending order every time a 1 occurs in the t column, to get this:

```
     t  z
 1: NA NA
 2: NA NA
 3: NA NA
 4:  1  1
 5: NA NA
 6: NA NA
 7: NA NA
 8: NA NA
 9:  1  2
10: NA NA
11:  1  3
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a logical index of non-NA elements in 'i' and assign ('z') as the sequence of 't'

```
dt[!is.na(t), z := seq_along(t)]
dt
#     t  z
# 1: NA NA
# 2: NA NA
# 3: NA NA
# 4:  1  1
# 5: NA NA
# 6: NA NA
# 7: NA NA
# 8: NA NA
# 9:  1  2
#10: NA NA
#11:  1  3
```

Answer (score 1):

subset on t==1 and take cumulative sum

```
  dt[t==1, z := cumsum(t)]
```

Answer (score 0):

with

```
library(dplyr)
```

`df <- data.frame(t = c(1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA))
df %>% group_by(t) %>% mutate(z = cumsum(t))`